# xsetwacom won't find Wacom tablet under 17.10 (but did with 17.04); multiple cursors, no touch control, etc

Tags: 17.10, tablet, wacom

I'm on 17.10 with a Wacom Bamboo Touch (not a new model) that's worked nicely in the past (up to 17.04) and which I could configure using xsetwacom.  Now, it shows up under xinput but not in `xsetwacom --list`.

So:

- There are two cursors.
- I can't turn off the touch function (without this ability, the stylus is nearly unusable)
- I don't have a command-line interface to control mapping-to-monitors

etc

Here's xinput:

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:13                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:13              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-touch:13                         id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-stylus:13                        id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-eraser:13                        id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-cursor:13                        id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pad:13                           id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:13                      id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Ideally, I'd like everything to work like it used to.

The Settings gui interface under Wayland does not offer these controls either (this is now a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1735216 )

Comment: Have you tried switching to an Xorg session? I wouldn't expect tools built around core Xorg components to be especially useful under Wayland.

Comment: No, I haven't. Can I switch back and forth? I was expecting that Wayland  would support common peripherals.

Comment: You can select between Wayland (the default), and Xorg, at the login screen, yes. The peripheral should work under Wayland, yes, but you can't use xinput/xsetwacom to configure it. You should be able to configure a Wacom in the tablet settings panel in system settings, but I don't know of any CLI tools to alter settings when under Wayland.

Comment: Thanks. Well, switching back to X11 was seamless. Goodbye, Wayland. :( @dobey, would you like to answer this question with a simple "go back to X"? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Tools based on X11 protocols for settings, such as xinput, xset, and xsetwacom will not work under Wayland, which is the default display system in 17.10. You will need to log out and select the Xorg session at the login screen, to be able to make use of such tools.

You should however, be able to configure these settings by going to *Settings* -> *Devices* -> *Wacom Tablet*, under Wayland.

Comment: Can you clarify "should"? I've edited my question to mention that the GUI is no substitute for the missing functionality. Therefore, there is so far *no alternative* but to revert to X11.

Comment: If that is true, can you please file a bug by running `ubuntu-bug gnome-control-center` to report the disparity between the UI and xsetwacom?

Comment: Okay; that's here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1735216   Thanks.